# RichFaces' TreeSelectionChangeEvent processed during Apply Request Phase

Tags: jsf-2, tree, richfaces, selectionchanged

during the migration from RichFaces 3 to 4, we are facing an unexpected behaviour of `rich:tree` element. We registered a `selectionChangeListener` which is supposed to include a facelet with `h:inputText` fields next to the tree depending on the new selection. The facelet is supposed to show detailed information on the selected node.

This works correctly when the first selection is made. However, when we select another node of the same type, the same facelet is included (which is correct in this case as the node type is the same), but the values of the previous node are displayed in the facelet, even though the object holding the value of the component is instantiated correctly.

Inspecting the log files revealed that the `TreeSelectionChangeEvent` is processed during the *Apply Request Phase* (2). During that phase, the object holding the textfield's value is updated correctly, but is changed back to the old value during *Update Model Phase* (4).

**General question** on this issue is: Is it correct that this event is processed during Apply Request Phase even though the `immediate` attribute of the tree is set to *false*? (I would have expected the event to be processed during Invoke Application Phase (5)) And, if this is correct behaviour, how could we circumvent the problem that the old value is restored?

Thanks for your suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as much as I understood, during the Apply Request Phase, the listener-event is executed and you update fields which are also represented as `h:inputFields` in the currently rendered view?

During Update Model Phase, the data out of the original `h:inputText` overwrites the already made changes?

Without being able to test it out locally: With `switchType="ajax"` the `rich:tree`-component gives two attributes

- `execute` and
- `render`.

You want the facelet-part to re-render, but not the input values to be executed (because that's what the listener already did).

Assuming you use `rich:tree` in ajax switch-type, have you tried to set `execute="@this"` and `render="<theFaceletComponent>"`?

If the component id wasn't found, use `:#{rich:clientId('<theFaceletComponent>')}` for an absolute identifier.

Hope, that helps ...